# Beautiful Soup and documents containing <text> tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to navigate and extract text from a quasi HTML document using Beautiful Soup that contains `<text>` elements. Each `<text>` element has sub elements that I need to get to.

Example doc

```html
<doc>
  <text>
    <content1>Some text here</content1>
    <content2>Some other text</content2>
  </text>
</doc>
```

So I can't use

```py
soup.doc.text.content1.text
```

to navigate the tree as .text has a special meaning in BS Tag elements and returns the concatenated text of all the child elements.

lxml has a 'solution' for this but I can't find anything similar for BS:

```py
root.doc['text'].content1.text
```

Comment: This is also XML rgt?

Comment: yes, not sure what you mean?

Comment: Are you required to use dot notation or can you use css selectors (for BS) or xpath (for lxml)?

Comment: At the moment I'm translating certain elements of the document to my own representation. By traversing the document elements depth-first, I end up with a representation that has the same order as the original. If I switch to query-type functions I wall lose that ordering.

Comment: To be clear, I don't have this specific problem with lxml as it does provide a way to get around the problem. However, the document I'm parsing is not well-formed XML, it is more like HTML and therefore needs a forgiving parser such as an HTML parser. Otherwise I would've stuck to lxml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `find()` function on the parent of the  element.

```py
soup.doc.find('text',recursive=False).content1.text
```